# Why is the response data going to the catch block after await in Axios?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, react-router-dom

**err.response.data giving back the data I am looking for !!**
Status code 302
The data is captured in the catch block instead of try block
[This is the reudx slice code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GpLs.png)

```
  export const getAllProject = async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    console.log("before");
    const res = await apiLink.get(`/getAllProjects`);

    console.log(res.data);
    console.log("after");
    dispatch(getAllProjectSuccess(res.data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data);
    //   toast.error(error.response?.data.message);
  }
};
```

The API is calling and the data is also coming.
I inspected the network tab
And also working in  postman
But after the await, the code is not running.
React router version 5 is used in this project.

[this is the proof of API calling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWOaR.png)
and
[using axios interceptor like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdByv.png)

```
apiLink.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const TOKEN = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));

    config.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer " + TOKEN;

    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

apiLink.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    return response;
  },
  function (err) {
    if (err.response?.status === 500) {
      userLogout();
    }

    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
);

export default apiLink;
```

**Edited:**

**err.response.data giving back the data I am looking for !!**
I just log that and the status code of receiving the data is **302** .

Comment: After which await? If you are using `axios` you don't need to call `json()` on the response, the body is already parsed.

Comment: I added this from stack over flow if i remove this same as before

Comment: You can't log `res` and `after` ? What's the network code you receive ?

Comment: yes i can't log after res , the network code is fine giving the expected data as response

Comment: Can you log the response inside the response interceptor ? If you do `console.log(error)` inside the catch block ,does it log any error ?

Comment: Why I am getting the data in the error function ?
err.response.data giving back the data I am looking for

Comment: I'd also like to know why you apparently log out the user if the response status was 500.

Comment: I am working for a client and he give me that API , if the token expire that give status code 500  , but who made this API I don't know , it should be 403

Comment: Have you logged the error in the response interceptor? There could be an error before the redirect, e.g., see https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/932.

Comment: message: "Request failed with status code 302"
name: "AxiosError" 
how to fix this ?

Comment: The be probably is sending back a wrong status along with right data. You can temporarily fix this by changing Promise.reject to Promise.resolve(err) inside the interceptor. That should just be temporary until they fix the be though.

Comment: thanks @Cesare 
got it res.response.data like this

Comment: but what kind of modification is needed in the backend to solve this issue ?

Comment: *The 302 status code is a redirection message that occurs when a resource or page you're attempting to load has been temporarily moved to a different location.*

Comment: so if the status code is 202 it will be working fine ?